# Ошибка при подключении к БД при помощи модуля PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

только начал разбираться с работой модуля PyMySQL и столкнулся со следующей ошибкой при попытке подключится к БД через переменную:

```
"try_to_connect = pymysql.connect(database_host, database_user, password, database_name)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given"
```

хотя все шаги делал согласно примеру в статье, не могу понять почему передаётся 5 аргументов. Код ниже:

```
import pymysql
database_host = "localhost"
database_user = 'root'
password = str(input("enter your password:" ))
database_name = 'sortings'
try_to_connect = pymysql.connect(database_host, database_user, password, database_name)
```

Comment: Явно передайте аргументы. host=, user=, и тд

Comment: @asanisimov, не догадался сразу залезть в библиотеку и посмотреть класс. Спасибо, Вы очень помогли.